# How to calculate variance between baseline 1 start and actual start in MS Project (2007)?

Tags: ms-project, ms-project-2007

I would like to find out the variance between baseline start 1 and actual start. However, I realised that the start variance value as seen from the Variance table actually shows the difference between the baseline and actual start. How should I go about getting this value? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In "Options", find the EV calculation choice and choose Baseline 1 for your EV calculations.  I don't have 2007 anymore so I can't direct you more specifically.  But the EV Calculation method is where you need to make the change from baseline to baseline 1.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to approach this is to save your old schedule as Baseline1, then do your schedule modifications and rebaseline as Baseline. I've found this to be a bit easier to remember to do compared to changing the EVM options.